# How to --enable-protocol=SRT of ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

all I am trying to --enable-protocol=SRT of ffmpeg. What I do as the following:
1.Check current configuration of ffmpeg which shows it doesn't suppport protocol of SRT.
[image]

2.So I trying to use msys64 to compile ffmpeg with --enable-protocol=SRT,and the command

`$ ./configure  --toolchain=msvc  --arch=x64  --enable-yasm  --enable-asm --enable-shared --enable-protocol=SRT`

but the result as the following:
[image] 
it's showing that the config is no use.Can you help me,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SRT is provided via an external library, so you'll need that library available for linking via pkg-config.

configure flags are `--enable-protocol=libsrt --enable-libsrt`. The former flag is only needed if you have disabled all components or protocols. Won't hurt to keep it, though.

Comment: “library available for linking via pkg-config”，I try to do it but failed,can you tell me how can I do it ?

Comment: You need to install pkg-config first